# ¿Porque después de haber ingresado de un login o haber hecho alguna consulta, el localhost se queda en blanco y no muestra el contenido?

Tags: php, html, xampp

"Después de ingresar desde el login, se queda en blanco y no muestra ningún resultado".

Aclaro el Xampp está conectado perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código de login1.php es muy simple:

```
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$BDatos="login";
$con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $BDatos);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error(),". Error No. ". mysqli_connect_errno();
  }

ini_set('display_errors', '1');     
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$User= $_POST['user'];
$Password= $_POST['password'];
$Numero= $_POST['numero'];
$Nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$Apellido= $_POST['apellido'];
$Email= $_POST['email'];
$UserRegistrado= $_POST['user_r'];
$PasswordRegistrado= $_POST['password_r'];


switch ($Numero) {

    case 1:

        $ingreso1 = "SELECT usID FROM TblUsuario WHERE usUser='$User' AND usPassword='$Password'";
        $proceso1 = mysqli_query($con, $ingreso1);
        $filas1 = mysqli_fetch_array($proceso1);

        if ($filas1) {
            $ID=$filas1[0];

        } else {
            echo "El usuario o contrseña es incorrecto, volver para reintentar el ingreso";
        }
        break;


        $ingreso2 = "SELECT usNombre, usApellido FROM TblUsuario where usID= '$ID'";
        $proceso1 = mysqli_query($con, $ingreso2);
        $filas2 = mysqli_fetch_array($proceso2);
        echo "<center>";

        if ($filas2) {
            echo "Hola! Bienvenido al sitio web de SST SENA";
            echo "<em>",$filas2['usNombre'],"";
            echo $filas2['usApellido'], "</em>";
            echo "<p>";

        } else {
            echo "El usuario o contrseña es incorrecto, volver para reintentar el ingreso";
        };

        
        $ingreso3= "SELECT rolNombre FROM TblRol, RelUsuarioxRol
        WHERE reluxr_usID= '$ID'";
        $proceso3 = mysqli_query($con, $ingreso3);

        while ($filas3= mysqli_fetch_array($proceso3)){
            echo "Su rol es: ";
            if ($filas3) {

                echo "<p>";
                echo "<b>", $filas3['rolNombre'], " ","</b>";

                $ROL= $filas3['rolNombre'];

                $ingreso4= "SELECT perNombre, modNombre 
                FROM RelPermisoxRolxModulo, TblRol, TblPermiso, TblModulo
                WHERE rolNombre = '$ROL'";

                $proceso4 = mysqli_query($con, $ingreso4);

                echo "<table border='1'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Permiso</th>";
                echo "<th' scope='col'>Modulo</th>";
                echo "</tr>";


                while ($filas4= mysqli_fetch_array($proceso4)){
                    if ($proceso4) {

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>", $filas4[0], " </th> ";
                        echo "<th>",$filas4[1], " </th>  ";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<p>";
                    } 
                }
                echo "</table>";    
                
                echo "<p>";

                echo "<h1> Para registrar una situación haga click en el enlace ⬇️ </h1>";
                echo  '<li><a href="indexformulario.php" target="_blank">Tarjeta de Observacion</a></li>';

                }
                else {
                echo "No tienes ningun rol";
                }
        };
        echo "</center>";

        break;

    case 2:

        $ingreso= "INSERT into TblUsuario (usNombre, usApellido ,usEmail, usUser, usPassword) 
        values ('$Nombre', '$Apellido', '$Email', '$UserRegistrado', '$PasswordRegistrado')";
        $proceso= mysqli_query($con, $ingreso); 

        if ($proceso) {
            echo "Bienvenido al sitio web SST SENA, sus datos han sido registrados, inicie sesión!";
        } else {
            echo "Sus datos no han sido registrados, intente de nuevo";
        };

        break;


}
```

.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Estos son los errores que me aparecieron:

Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landing\login1.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key "apellido" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landing\login1.php on line 21

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landing\login1.php on line 22

Warning: Undefined array key "user_r" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landing\login1.php on line 23

Warning: Undefined array key "password_r" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Landing\login1.php on line 24

Código del formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Login SST</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/logo.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="forms-container">
        <div class="signin-signup">
          <form action="login1.php" method="post" class="sign-in-form">
            <h2 class="title"> Ingresar </h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="numero" value="1" class="btn solid" />
            <p class="social-text"> Ingresar con: </p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
          <form action="login1.php" method="post" class="sign-up-form">
            <h2 class="title"> Registrarse </h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="user_r" placeholder="Login" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password_r" placeholder="Contraseña" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="2" />
            <p class="social-text"> Registrate con: </p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panels-container">
        <div class="panel left-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3> ¿Eres nuevo por aqui? </h3>
            <p>
              Registrate a nuestro sitio web, para disfrutar de las diferentes herramientas que tiene el sistema SST del SENA CBA. 
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">
              Registrarse
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="assets/img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel right-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3> ¿Ya tienes cuenta aqui? </h3>
            <p>
              Inicia sesion y disfruta de nuestro sitio web. 
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">
              Ingresar
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="assets/img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y, ¿qué hay en `login1.php`? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar el código.

Comment: Ya lo agregué, espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Poco podemos hacer con un código incompleto. Te aconsejo que aprendas a depurar el código, más adelante podrás hacerlo revisando el log de errores, por lo pronto, pon estas tres líneas al inicio de tu bloque PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` guarda el archivo y vuelve a probar, ahora verás en pantalla los errores, cópialos y pégalos en la pregunta para que podamos ver cuál es el problema realmente.

Comment: Te entiendo solo que soy un principiante en programación por lo cual aún no se depurar el código.  Ya agregué los errores que me aparecieron

Comment: Ahora pon el código completo, pulsando en [edit], si es demasiado código, pon al menos esas líneas que ponen los mensajes de error, y las líneas que están más arriba de esas. Es que sin ver el código, cómo creas las variables, etc, no podemos adivinar las cosas.

Comment: Pon también el código desde el cual llamas a `login1.php`, ¿qué es, es un formulario, es una URL? Lo que parece que está ocurriendo es que no está recibiendo los datos en la superglobal `$_POST`.

Comment: Es un formulario para ingresar y otro para registrarse, al momento de ingresar el switch hará el caso uno, pero si se registra hará el caso 2.

Comment: Perdón, pero soy un poco nuevo en esta página, no me deja colocar las variables al editar. Dice que el código no está bien estructurado. ¿Te lo puedo mostrar en foto?

Comment: A ver, copia y pega el código, luego seleccionas todo el bloque de código y pulsa en el símbolo **`{ }`** que aparece en la barra de edición. Si no sabes hacerlo ponlo tal cual y ya lo arreglaremos. Sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte, no somos adivinos. Evita las capturas de imágen, no sirven de nada en este caso, necesitamos ver el texto del código.

Comment: Y, como te dije en otro comentario, necesitamos ver el código del formulario, desde el cual llamas a `login1.php`, parece que no pusiste las etiquetas `name` en ese `form` o no apuntas al archivo correcto o lo que sea.

Comment: Ya agregué los dos códigos finalmente, gracias. Los name si los coloque en todos los campos del formulario. Se me salto colocarle el name al segundo submit al parecer.

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste entonces o sigue dando error? Algo que no se entiende es que tienes dos `form` ¿?

Comment: Sigue dando los mismos errores. Si dos form uno para el login y el otro para que se registren

Comment: Pues deberías dirigir cada uno a su propio archivo, por ejemplo, para el registro puedes crear un archivo `register.php`, y dirigir el `form` de registro a ese archivo. Es que todo mezclado, habrá siempre inputs cuyo `name` no estará, ese es el motivo de los *`Undefined index`* que tienes. Sea como sea, siempre que recojas datos de `$_POST` deberías usar `isset`, o ternarios o fusión de null.

Comment: faltaría un valor/case predeterminado para `switch ($Numero) {`

Answer (score 1):

El único error que veo es que el submit del segundo formulario no tiene nombre, entonces no podrá ejecutar la condición ya que necesita recibir el dato para su ejecución, si nos damos cuenta empieza a dar error desde esa línea, porque después de "numero" sigue "nombre" por otra parte podrías utilizar un input hidden para agregar el valor allí en lugar de utilizar el submit, es solo una sugerencia.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" name="numero" value="2" />
```

Para más información puedes ver éste articulo
[Input Type Hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo indicado por la respuesta de @addonisdl, fíjate que estás intentando leer siempre todos los datos conjuntos de ambos formularios, cuando en cada uno usas campos distintos, y eso provocará que siempre te de error en alguna de las asignaciones.

Lo puedes solucionar a lo bruto cambiando esto:

```
$User= $_POST['user'];
$Password= $_POST['password'];
$Numero= $_POST['numero'];
$Nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$Apellido= $_POST['apellido'];
$Email= $_POST['email'];
$UserRegistrado= $_POST['user_r'];
$PasswordRegistrado= $_POST['password_r'];
```

por esto:

```
$User= $_POST['user'] ?? '';
$Password= $_POST['password'] ?? '';
$Numero= $_POST['numero'] ?? '';
$Nombre= $_POST['nombre'] ?? '';
$Apellido= $_POST['apellido'] ?? '';
$Email= $_POST['email'] ?? '';
$UserRegistrado= $_POST['user_r'] ?? '';
$PasswordRegistrado= $_POST['password_r'] ?? '';
```

Es decir, usando el **[Operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)** `??` que no es más que una abreviación de este código en todos ellos:

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $User= $_POST['user'];
} else {
    $User= '';
}
```

De este modo, los $_POST que no estén definidos no te darán error y se asignarán vacios a esas variables, que seguramente no usas dentro del **case** que estés recibiendo en el **name** *numero* del botón submit correspondiente de cada formulario.

Recuerda hacer el cambio indicado por la respuesta de  @addonisdl también!

Answer (score 0):

Convendría que para este caso apliques el *principio de responsabilidad única*, porque un Login es una cosa y un Registro es otra cosa. Si lo piensas bien, en cualquier sitio verás de entrada una pantalla para el Login y en alguna parte un botón o un enlace para el Registro, nunca vas a ver dos formularios, uno para el Login y otro para el Registro. De hecho, aparte de los formularios, veo que tienes en el HTML un botón `sign-up-btn` y otro botón `sign-in-btn` ... es algo contradictorio y deberías clarificar un poco el contexto, aplicando responsabilidad única.

No obstante, si por algún motivo tiene que ser así (dos formularios, rompiendo totalmente el estándar y las buenas prácticas), puedes aplicar algunas cosas que simplifiquen el trabajo. La hoja de ruta a aplicar podría ser:

1. Identificar el tipo de proceso que deba realizarse (Login o Registro) cosa que ya haces, dando el valor `1` o `2`
2. Igualar los `name` de los `input` que se repitan en cada formulario
3. Usar ternarios o fusión de null para verificar que los input traen datos
4. Organizar mejor el código. Aquí he optado por funciones. De hecho, hay cosas extrañas y erróneas, como romper los `case` con `break;` en varios puntos, aparte de que no se entiende por qué haces **tantas consultas SQL en el case `1`** ¿?. Puedes perfectamente traer todo lo que necesites en una sola consulta, uniendo las tablas mediante `JOIN`. He intentado construir una sola consulta, pero dado que usas JOIN implícito, no se ve claro cuáles son las relaciones entre tablas. En el case `1` he dejado el ingreso inicial, que verificar usuario y password. Si explicas las relaciones entre las tablas se te puede mostrar cómo construir una sola instrucción SQL usando `JOIN`, no tiene sentido consultar una y otra vez para tablas relacionadas.

Los formularios quedarían así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/64d58efce2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Login SST</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/logo.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="forms-container">
        <div class="signin-signup">
          <form action="login1.php" method="post" class="sign-in-form">
            <h2 class="title"> Ingresar </h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="numero" value="1" class="btn solid" />
            <p class="social-text"> Ingresar con: </p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
          <form action="login1.php" method="post" class="sign-up-form">
            <h2 class="title"> Registrarse </h2>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Login" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="numero" value="2" />
            <p class="social-text"> Registrate con: </p>
            <div class="social-media">
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="social-icon">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panels-container">
        <div class="panel left-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3> ¿Eres nuevo por aqui? </h3>
            <p>
              Registrate a nuestro sitio web, para disfrutar de las diferentes herramientas que tiene el sistema SST del SENA CBA. 
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">
              Registrarse
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="assets/img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel right-panel">
          <div class="content">
            <h3> ¿Ya tienes cuenta aqui? </h3>
            <p>
              Inicia sesion y disfruta de nuestro sitio web. 
            </p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">
              Ingresar
            </button>
          </div>
          <img src="assets/img/log.svg" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahora pasemos a `login1.php`, que quedaría así (he modificado varias cosas y he organizado mejor el código, queda cubrir la enorme laguna del JOIN, pero no será complicado si explicas cómo se relacionan las tablas, lo que tienes en tu código actual es un verdadero spaghetti, lanzando cuatro consultas cuando puedes lanzar sólo una):

```
/*
    En primer lugar, vamos a determinar 
    qué botón fue presionado, para saber 
    el tipo de acción que debe ejecutarse: Login o Registro
    Usaremos fusión de null
    Si trabajas en PHP < 7 cambia todas las recogidas de $_POST 
    por este estilo:
    $User= !empty($_POST['numero']) ? $_POST['numero'] : NULL;
        
    En segundo lugar, organizaremos el código usando funciones
    esto permite un código más limpio y más fácil de depurar                
*/
$Numero = $_POST['numero'] ?? NULL;
if ($Numero) {
    echo loginOrRegister(); 
} else {
    echo "Ninguno de los botones fueron presionados";
}

/*
    Función que retorna la conexión a la base de datos
*/
function getConnection() {
    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $BDatos="login";
    $con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $BDatos);
    return $con;        
}

/*
    Función que determina si debe hacerse un Login o un Registro 
    Es el switch ... case que tenías originalmente, 
    pero llamando para cada case una función propia
*/
function loginOrRegister() {
    $User= $_POST['user'] ?? NULL;
    $Password= $_POST['password'] ?? NULL;
    $Numero= $_POST['numero'] ?? NULL;
    $Nombre= $_POST['nombre'] ?? NULL;
    $Apellido= $_POST['apellido'] ?? NULL;
    $Email= $_POST['email'] ?? NULL;

    switch ($Numero) {      
        case 1:
            if($User && $Password) {
                return doLogin($User,$Password);                    
            } else {
                return "Faltan datos en el POST para Login";    
            }
            break;  
            
        case 2:
            if($Nombre && $Apellido && $Email && $User && $Password) {
                return doRegister($Nombre, $Apellido, $Email, $User, $Password);
            } else {
                return "Faltan datos en el POST para Registro";                     
            }
            break;
        default:
            return "No se cumple ningún case";
            break;
    }
}

/*
    Función dedicada a hacer el Login 
    Pendiente de completar, haciendo una consulta SQL
    que haga JOIN de todas las tablas implicadas,
    no lanzando una consulta SQL por cada tabla, lo cual es absurdo 
    Las base de datos son RELACIONALES y tu código ignora totalmente eso.
    No lo he hecho porque no queda claro cómo se relacionan las tablas
*/
function doLogin($User,$Password) {
    $sql = "SELECT usID FROM TblUsuario WHERE usUser='$User' AND usPassword='$Password'";
    if ($con = getConnection()) {
        $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        return mysqli_fetch_array($stmt) ? "Estás logueado" : "Credenciales incorrectas";                   
    } else {
        return "Error de conexión";
    }
}

/*
    Función que hace el registro 
    Aquí he verificado las filas afectadas
    Es la forma segura de saber que se insertó el registro 
*/
function doRegister($Nombre, $Apellido, $Email, $User, $Password) {
    $sql= "INSERT into TblUsuario (usNombre, usApellido ,usEmail, usUser, usPassword) 
values ('$Nombre', '$Apellido', '$Email', '$User', '$Password')";
    if ($con = getConnection()) {
        $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($stmt && mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
            return "Bienvenido al sitio web SST SENA, sus datos han sido registrados, inicie sesión!";
        } else {
            return "Sus datos no han sido registrados, intente de nuevo";
        }
    } else {
        return "No hay conexión a la Base de Datos";        
    }
}
```